# How to consume component from file in different folder

Tags: coldfusion, cfc

Working with version: 2016,0,10,314028

I know there are other questions addressing the issue, but since they are a bit old I wonder if anything has changed since then. Here is my problem:

In the "OnRequestStart" function inside Application.cfc (located in root folder), I have this:
`<cfset application.cfclogin = "comp.login" />`
"comp" begin the folder and login the name of the cfc file.

Inside the same Application I consume the cfc without a problem, like this:
`<cfinvoke component="#application.cfclogin#" method="sgice_redirect" >`

Even in a logout.cfm file located in root, the same cfinvoke method works.
But if a try the same cfinvoke from a file located in /subfolder/Layout.cfm for example, the cfinvoke throws an Error. Which looks like this:

[image]

I tried putting the name of the app in the dot notation declaration (APP.folder.cfcfile) but that doesn't work even in the files located in root invoking the cfc.
Other websites inside the same server are using this method of declaring the dot notation name for the cfc inside OnRequestStart and using that variable throughout the files, but I can't find the reason of this not working in this specific site. If you are wondering about the F:/ route, F:/WebSitesTij/CFSites/sit_tij/ is supposed to be my root folder in this case. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using the entire directory path when setting your application variable?

Comment: @DanBracuk Do you mean the whole "F:/folder/folder/cfcfolder/cfcfile" ?

Comment: That's what I mean.

Comment: Call `expandPath("/")` in the folder where you get the error. It will tell you what CF considers to be the root path when resolving the component package path. If there's no `SGICE` folder on that level, you found your problem.

Comment: DanBracuk suggestion didn't work for me, I'll try your tip @Alex

Comment: Hey @Alex, I don't know why, but the path described by that function is:
"F:\WebSitesTij_home\"
I don't know where dit it came up with the "_home" part.
Does it mean that ```<cfinvoke>´´´ starts searching in that non existing folder?

Comment: @AlanVelasco That is exactly what is happening. You either have to fix your site setup (depends on how your connector/webserver is set up) or specify a mapping in the `Application.cfc` to route `SGICE` to a specific real path, e.g.: `<cfset this.mappings["/SGICE"] = "F:/WebSitesTij/CFSites/sit_tij/">`.

Comment: My whole project is being moved to a shiny new network folder and a new url tomorrow (the current one was temporary). I'll ask for that configuration to the admin as soon as possible.
In the meantime, do you have any tutorial or guide for mappings @Alex ? I've seen that subject pop up whenever I saw answers to the problem I have in other Stack Questions or in other sites. Thanks.